# Number of edges of any spanning tree of a graph G coming from a subgraph of G

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Consider a simple undirected, unweigthed graph $G=(V,E)$ and its edge-induced subgraph $G^{*}=(V^{*},E^{*})$. Suppose that $G$ and $G^{*}$ have $c$ and $c^{*}$ connected components, respectively. Is it true that exactly

$$|V^{*}|-\min\{0,c-c^{*}\}$$

edges can be selected for any spanning tree of $G$ from $E^{*}$? Could somebody give a proof/counterexample? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you mean a particular edge-induced subgraph?

Comment: What is "particular" in your sense?

Comment: The edge-induced subgraph depends on which edges you pick to induce the subgraph.  Is your claim for some particular set of edges?

Comment: $E^{*}$ is an arbitrary subset of $E$. $V^{*}$ contains exactly all the endpoints of the edges in $E^{*}$.

Comment: Would picking any one edge not lead to a counterexample?  Pick a spanning tree with that edge.  it has 1 edge from $E^*$.  $|V^*|=2$, and $c\geq c^*$ because one edge is connected.

Comment: Oh, I understand it. I would like to get the number of all the independent 4-membered cycles in a bipartite, unweighted, undirected simple graph $(V,E)$. To do this, I have picked up all the edges which are in some 4-membered cycles of $(V,E)$, making a $(V^{*},E^{*})$ subgraph of the original one. I have thought that I get the number of all the independent 4-membered cycles in $(V,E)$ of with the expression $$E^{*}-|V^{*}|+\min\{0,c-c^{*}\}.$$ Would be it true independently of the question above?

Comment: Is a 4-membered cycle a cycle with 4 vertices?

Comment: Yes, and naturally, with four edges.

Comment: Would a square be a counterexample to that?  The expression comes out to 0, but there is 1 4-membered cycle.

Comment: :( Would  you have an idea how to get the number of all the independent four cycles of (V,E)?

Comment: Could it be true, if at least two 4-cycles is in (V,E)?

Comment: See Theorem 1 of http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/126802/MathSlov_21-1971-1_6.pdf

Comment: And no, it is not true even if at least two 4-cycles are in (V,E).  For a counterexample, any number of disjoint squares leads to your expression to give 0.

Comment: Theorem 1 from dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/126802/ is related to the independent 4-cycles or all the 4-cycles?

Comment: If by independent you mean "not sharing any vertices" I don't see anything to suggest that this is what is being referred to, but I haven't looked at it carefully.  Might do so tomorrow; have to go now.

Comment: Two cycles are independent if their symmetric difference is nonempty (i.e. they have not common edges). There is a maximally independent subset of all the cycles spanning all the cycles with the symmetric difference operation.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit later than I suggested in my previous comment, but it appears that Theorem 1 of the paper refers to all 4-cycles, with no condition on independence.

Answer (score 0):

No; for a counterexample let $E^*$ consist of one edge of $G$, and pick any spanning tree.

$\min\{0,c-c^{*}\}=0$ because $c^*=1$ because $G^*$ is connected, so the expression is just $|V^{*}|=2>1$, so it cannot be the number of edges in the spanning tree from $E^*$.